# Unable to reference my own packages

Tags: go

I have created an interface as well as a struct, but every time I save my Go file, the compiler is formatting away my `import` statement and indicating that my struct is undefined.

I'm totally new to Go, so this probably seems obvious to someone. I've read the documentation.

Here's my file structure:
[image]

How do I properly reference a type I've created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to qualify a name when it's coming from another package. Try `models.HttpResult` in the file on the left.

Comment: That was simpler than I thought! I'm used to the C# using/namespace system, where you don't need to prefix the name.